# Mocha before function - lambda without curly braces errors; lambda with curly braces works

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, mockgoose

This code makes my mocha tests pass without error:

```
before(done => {
  mockgoose
    .prepareStorage()
    .then(() => mongoose.connect('mongodb://example.com/TestingDB'))
    .then(done)
})

it('passes', done => done())
```

But removing the curly braces in the `before` block causes the error:

```
before(done =>
  mockgoose
    .prepareStorage()
    .then(() => mongoose.connect('mongodb://example.com/TestingDB'))
    .then(done)
)

it('passes', done => done())

1) "before all" hook

0 passing (2s)
1 failing

1)  "before all" hook:
    Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Does anyone know why?  If more context is needed, I can oblige.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says so right there, you weren't returning anything before, you were just using `done` to specify when the task is done. Now you are returning a `Promise` (the result of the mockgoose call i'd assume) and it's confusing mocha.

Comment: Ahhhh, yes.  By using the lambda without curly braces, I there's an implicit return!  So by no curly braces, I was returning a Promsie.  And by supplying `done`, I was also specifying a callback.  I'll just get rid of the `done` and be on my merry way.  Thanks!  I'm new to this Javascript scene :)